# Issue getting a submit button to center in a wrap

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cannot get the submit button to center. I have tried everything from `text-align: center;` to `margin: 0 auto;` to a left and right margin at auto. The button will not center anyway I try. What am I failing to do?

```css
.contactForm {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
.contactButton {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 425px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #800000;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactForm">
  <form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform">
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <label for="contactButton">
      <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="submit">
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You may also want to replace `width: 425px;` with some percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align:center` on the parent div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopal/su3vg018/

```
.contactForm {
 text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to center is, because it is inside a label. The label is an inline element too and will size around the button. Therefor `text-align: center` and other solutions don't work.

In the snippet below, I've made the label show itself as a block element, which automatically occupies the available width of the parent. Then you can easily center the button inside it:

The added piece:

```
label[for="contactButton"] {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The whole code:

```css
.contactForm {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
.contactButton {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 425px;
  /* Make sure the button isn't too wide on small screens */
  max-width: 80%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #800000;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

label[for="contactButton"] {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactForm">
  <form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform">
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <label for="contactButton">
      <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="submit">
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.contactForm label[for="contactButton"] {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```